# Could we have more than 1 topic challenge?

Tags: feature-request, topic-challenge

I think we should have 2 topic challenges.

1. **Meta-puzzle Topic Challenge**.
   Meta-puzzles are good puzzles, it's good to encourage members here to keep creating Meta-puzzles. But they're hard to create, 
   so we need long duration for this. I suggest 1 to 2 months is ideal for this,
   so in a year there will be 6 to 12 periods.
2. **Fortnight Topic Challenge**
   As usual topic challenge.

Comment: Not necessarily a bad idea, but the topic challenges require volunteers to keep them going, and it seems that they are already flagging for lack of impetus.  Maintaining 2 challenges would require that much more work (and may confuse people as well).

Comment: I think MetaPuzzles could just be another extended Fortnight challenge.  I would suggest clarifying beforehand that the topic will last longer than normal so users can take the extra time to build the puzzles.  There was also the [community metapuzzle](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5588/2071), which I'm sure could be done again at some point.

Answer (score 3):

What you're proposing here seems to be to have ordinary fortnight challenges as we already do, plus an extra layer of topic challenge just for a single tag, which is always the same tag. That seems equivalent to just announcing that **metapuzzles are a particularly encouraged tag**.

A better way of doing that, without needing to get consensus from the entire community, would be to announce that you, personally, will reward good metapuzzles with bounties - and if you want to reward questions instead of answers, encourage metapuzzle OPs to post [wrap-ups](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5420/5373). See also [List of bounties with no deadlines](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4399/5373) for an example of how this sort of thing has been done here before.

Alternatively, just create a new post here on meta with a list of all metapuzzles. The thing is, it's not really a timed topic challenge if the topic is always the same - it's just promotion of a particular tag. Which you're free to do, of course, but why mix it up with the topic challenges?

Comment: Ok.... wrap-ups is the best way to encourage OPs puzzles, not only metapuzzle, although not many doing this. And I think, giving bounties will not work well, because if OPs do not post wrap-ups the bounty will be useless.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya You can post a comment on the question requesting a wrap-up so you can offer a bounty to the OP.  That gives them a notification that you want to award them for their work.